# Let's exclude tags one has already entered

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface

On Stack sites there is a constant fight for reducing redundant entities. We don't like too many answers, we don't like pointless comments, we don't like anything that wastes our time in vain.

I'm asking about small UI-enhancement, which actually can save us milliseconds, but I believe there is sense in such feature.

I'm asking to exclude tags from suggested tags if I have already entered this very tag.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were the great Atwood, I would be tempted to decline this. I don't think that it would pass a cost-benefit analysis test (a couple man hours for something which is really not a bug nor a needed feature).

That said, you are right and I completely agree. I'm just betting (sadly) that it doesn't make business sense.

Comment: It's all about the polish. There are dozens of Q&A platforms available, but StackExchange has a pervasive quality that others lack.  A couple man-hours (likely less, though it's hard to estimate without seeing the code) so hundreds of thousands of people don't have to try to filter redundant tags?  Do it!