# Don't show in the "suggested tags" list tags that have already been added in the tag list

Tags: feature-request, tags

Don't show in the "suggested tags" list tags that have already been added in the tag list.

[image]

Comment: You want to have them simply removed, right? Not being replaced with a fresh tag from the top 10 of suggested tags?

Comment: @rene being replaced with a fresh tag from the top 10 of suggested tags would be my preference, assuming that the top 10 of suggested tags is decent (can be tested by analyzing user clicks).

Comment: Just removing might be low hanging fruit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let's exclude tags one has already entered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108568/282094) and related 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251862/282094 and *distantly requested* https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/219814/282094

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure that first question uses the same data. That suggests a tag based on the input in the tag area, while the suggestions in this question are made on the conten of the question body IIRC.

Comment: @Mast it's not clear that it's different, how is the **result** any different?

Comment: @Rob in the first question you linked to, the issue is with tag autocompletion, not tag suggestion. For the other two questions, it seems about tag synonyms.

Comment: Do you like https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146805/282094 more?

Comment: @Rob thanks for the link to this question but this is still about tag autocompletion, not tag suggestion.

Comment: Same underlying algorithm, they'll all be status-completed, if and when. My comment is automatically generated by the Review Queue, and has three upvotes; the first person gets the credit / pings from new users. Since you're experienced you're aware of the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/282094): `Questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers.` and `... try to look at the proposed target from the perspective and perceived skill level of the asker ...` and `... the guidelines for closing a question as a duplicate are much broader on meta sites, ...`, etc.

Comment: @Rob "same underlying algorithm" -> Source? suggesting tags sounds algorithmically different from autocomplete the tag that the user is currently writing.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344247/282094

Comment: @Rob where does it explain that it is same underlying algorithm?